# Extract one random second from an audio file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to find out a way in Fedora 17 to extract a random second from a given audio file using a console command.

Is there a YUM package that could help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sox you can edit audio files in command line
If you need exactly one second this will extract the second between 00:16 and 00:17

```
sox input.wav output.wav trim 00:00:16 00:00:01
```

The first argument of trim is the beginning of the trim and the second its duration.

If you use the command `soxi`, you can get the duration of your audio file.

If you manage to do a little script which get the duration of your file and take a random number lesser than this duration, I think you're good :)